# Hello! I want to create constructor for my class and I have an error: Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer swift

Tags: swift

I want to create constructor for my class and I have an error:

> Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
>   swift.

---

```
class MyPicker: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var pickerContent: [String] = [""]
    var textField = UITextField()

    var form: Form!

    init(form: Form, content: [String]) {
        self.form = form
        self.pickerContent = content
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463685/swift-super-init-isnt-called-on-all-paths-before-returning-from-initializer?noredirect=1#comment93799523_53463685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
```

in your init, class need to init it's super class

Comment: Thanks, you too )))