# Problems getting around 'Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer swift.'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement a BPM counter into a basic iOS app.

I'm using [this](http://joelperry.net/mac-os-x/simple-taptempo-class-for-swift/) implementation in an XCode project, connecting the `addTap` method to an onscreen button.

However, I receive the error.

> Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer swift.

So following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873071/hello-i-want-to-create-constructor-for-my-class-and-i-have-an-error-super-init) answer I found by searching here, I realised I have to call `super.init()` as defined in the UIViewController class.

I've done that, as shown below - but now I'm getting another compiler error

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSCoder.Type' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'

What I have at the minute is pasted below, TIA

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

private let timeOutInterval: TimeInterval
private let minTaps: Int
private var taps: [Date] = []

init(timeOut: TimeInterval, minimumTaps: Int) {
    timeOutInterval = timeOut
    minTaps = minimumTaps
    super.init(coder:NSCoder)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



func addTap() -> Double? {
    let thisTap = NSDate()

    if let lastTap = taps.last {
        if thisTap.timeIntervalSince(lastTap) > timeOutInterval {
            taps.removeAll()
        }
    }

    taps.append(thisTap as Date)
    guard taps.count >= minTaps else { return nil }
    guard let firstTap = taps.first else { return nil }

    let avgIntervals = thisTap.timeIntervalSince(firstTap) / Double(taps.count - 1)
    return 60.0 / avgIntervals
}


@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
self.display.text = String(addTap())
}
```

}

Comment: `init(coder:)` is used to initialize a VC that was designed in IB. Try calling `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` instead.

Comment: One more note - I usually try to call `super.init` as early as possible to let the superclass do "it's thing". If you're still getting errors, move the init call to be done first.

Comment: @dfd Don't try, know The rule is: First initialize all stored properties of the current class then call `super` (which is correct in this case).

Comment: @vadian, I didn't know that. That's what I get for learning OOP on my own 22 years ago! I'll keep that rule in mind. :-)

Comment: @dfd It's really worth it to read [The Swift Programming Language: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: @vadian, Thank you for the link. I will learn it. I'm sure I'll pick up much from that chapter. My fault for thinking I understand what is good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the line:

```
super.init(coder:NSCoder)
```

The parameter needs to be an instance of `NSCoder`, not the class itself. But you shouldn't even be calling that initializer.

Change that line to:

```
super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

Comment: However - now upon running the code, I get a blank white screen and the fatal error that init(coder:) has not been implemented